# Running in low graphics mode - existing suggestions fail to solve the problem

Tags: graphics, xorg

without being able to recall having installed anything new etc, my system now shows the low graphic mode message when I try to boot.

Curiously, when I choose the recovery mode, followed by resume, I can log in and the system seems to work fine, however external screens aren't recognized, and there may well be other limitations that I cannot identify.

I tried the following suggestions from the various threads concerning this problem, and none of them worked:

- I re-installed `ubuntu-desktop`
- I checked that I have sufficient space on the / directory (81% used)
- I investigated the settings for the `greeter`, but I don't have a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (could this be the issue?)
- I tried switching to `gdm`, however, the system just hung up on reboot (I gave up after 30min)
- I reinstalled `xserver-xorg`
- I installed `fglrx` but then neither the normal or the recovery mode would boot, but run in low graphics mode.

So I am running out of ideas. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a dell laptop, and use the "standard" X.Org X server AMD/ATI display driver. Running

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller

$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c04] (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:8c18] (rev d4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:8c1a] (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:8c1c] (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 [8086:8c1e] (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c4f] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
0e:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8520] (rev 01)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.